# How to properly re-encode a type that is sometimes encoded as an object, and sometimes as an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, object, encoding, decoding

I am encoding and decoding coordinates that are sometimes encoded as an object `{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3}` and sometimes as an array `[1,2,3]`.

For decoding, this poses no problem. I'll add the code at the end, but it is rather trivial and uninteresting. However, for re-encoding, I absolutely must be certain the coordinates are encoded back into the exact same way I found them, either object or array.

What is the best way to achieve that ? Should I use a private variable that remembers which kind of source they came from ? Make `Coordinates` a protocol and have two different structs implement it ? Something else I haven't thought of ?

Please note that I know in advance which encoding is going to be used. The API I'm interfacing with just hasn't updated everything to use objects yet, which is their newest standard as far as I understand. The outcome is not random.

---

Here is my current decoding logic :

```swift
extension Coordinates : Codable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case x
        case y
        case z
    }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) {
            
            self.x = try container.decode(Element.self, forKey: .x)
            self.y = try container.decodeIfPresent(Element.self, forKey: .y)
            self.z = try container.decode(Element.self, forKey: .z)
            
        } else if var container = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            
            self.x = try container.decode(Element.self)
            self.z = try container.decode(Element.self)
            
            if let z = try? container.decode(Element.self) {
                self.y = self.z
                self.z = z
            }
            
        } else {
            preconditionFailure("Cannot decode coordinates")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best" way? Best in what way?

Comment: You can preserve the structure using a simple enum

Comment: @Sweeper That is a good point. I guess I'm asking if there is a canonical way to do that.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Having an array and an object case and differentiating the encode / decode method based on that ? The problem is enums cannot contain stored properties so either that's not what you meant or it doesn't fit the purpose.

Comment: I don't think there is a canonical way. I've seen many `Codable` questions, and yours is the first one that I've seen such requirements. Both of the solutions you mentioned in your question sound like they would work.

Comment: @Sweeper Well I have to re-encode the files I'm decoding the same way they were, else they'll be invalid. I'm surprised this is an unusual requirement ! I have tried both solutions and I know they work, my question is mostly about software design rather than strictly coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an XY problem. Instead of trying to be super smart, I just added an `array` computed property to `Coordinates` and will encode that instead of the Coordinates themselves when that is required :

```swift
/**
 A spatial position with `XYZ` coordinates, `Y` being optional.
*/
struct Coordinates<Element : Coordinate> : Codable {
    
    /**
     West to East axis coordinate.
     */
    var x : Element
    
    /**
     Down to Up axis coordinate.
     */
    var y : Element?
    
    /**
     North to South axis coordinate.
     */
    var z : Element
    
    /**
     The coordinates in the form `[x, z]` or `[x, y, z]`.
     */
    var array : [Element] {
        if let y {
            return [x, y, z]
        } else {
            return [x, z]
        }
    }

    init(x : Element, y : Element? = nil, z : Element) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    }
}
```

```swift
//Normal encoding
struct Something {
    var coordinates : Coordinates<Int>
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(coordinates)
    }
}

//Array encoding
struct SomethingElse {
    var coordinates : Coordinates<Int>
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(coordinates.array)
    }
}
```

I don't mind that this forces me to explicitly implement encoding methods, as everything in this file format / API is busted and requires me to custom encode/decode anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve the structured data structure with a simple enum like:

```
enum Structured {
    case array([Element])
    case object(Coordination)
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case x
        case y
        case z
    }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) {
            let x = try container.decode(Element.self, forKey: .x)
            let y = try container.decodeIfPresent(Element.self, forKey: .y)
            let z = try container.decode(Element.self, forKey: .z)
            self = .object( Coordination(x: x, y: y, z: z) )
        } else if var container = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            let array = try container.decode([Element].self)
            self = .array( array )
        } else {
            preconditionFailure("Cannot decode coordinates")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does solve the issue it also makes using said coordinates rather cumbersome. I think however that I know what the right solution is now.